# Specify desktop in which application should open from shell script

Tags: shell, desktop

I have the following shell script on my MacBook, which runs when I type `gitrdone`:

```
open -a UC-One
code
open -a Mail
open -a Thunderbird
open -a Slack
open -a Sequel\ Pro
```

It opens the apps I want when I start my regular developer work. (The line with `code` runs another shell script that opens other applications.) But it tends to open all those applications in one or two desktops. Is there a way to control which desktop (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4...) each application opens in?

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27050/how-to-start-an-application-on-a-different-workspace) help you in any way?